# Diagonalization of an endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and $K[X,Y]$ be the polynomial ring in two variables. 
Consider the endomorphism $\Delta \in End_K (K[X,Y]$,

$\Delta : f \mapsto X \cdot \delta_X (f) + Y \cdot \delta_Y (f)F$,

where $\delta_X$ is the derivation to $X$.

Can somebody answer the question, whether $\Delta$ is diagonalizable or not and if, what is it's eigenspace decomposition?

And what is for $K= \mathbb Z / p \mathbb Z$, where $p$ is prim?

Comment: The set consisting of $X^mY^n$ for various powers, $m,n$ is a basis. Can you check what is $\Delta (X^mY^n)$?

Comment: So that's $(n+m) X^m Y^n$. But I still do not see how to go on..

Comment: Your question was if it is diagonalizable; what you have calculated should answer that.